# Not able to capture text using Selenium in Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium in Java to capture values from the below code snippet. But it's returning a null value.

```html
<div class="selenium" style="max-height: 0px !important; max-width: 0px !important;">
<div class="share metric">
<span id="nsf" class="nsf">
"2.2210636079249215+2.224479431183342+2.2244191794364805+2.2635962763351296+2.289855072463768+2.3309352517985613+2.3216783216783217+2.360018509949098+null+2.042235790730032+0.000006222369997702123+0</span></div>
```

I tried using

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='share metric']/span[@id='nsf']")).getAttribute("value")
```

and

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='share metric']/span[@id='nsf']")).gettext()
```

Comment: try other ways of extracting data like class, id, etc. sometimes selenium is unable to find element by a method

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath is wrong, the span tag is not a child of `<div class="share metric">`.

Why using xpath at all? Localting the element by it's `id` works just fine.

**code:**

```
    WebElement nsf = driver.findElement(By.id("nsf"));
    String text = nsf.getText();
    System.out.println(text);
```

**output:**

```
tarting ChromeDriver 101.0.4951.41 (93c720db8323b3ec10d056025ab95c23a31997c9-refs/branch-heads/4951@{#904}) on port 28658
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
[1655279888.338][WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 102.
Čer 15, 2022 9:58:08 DOP. org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
"2.2210636079249215+2.224479431183342+2.2244191794364805+2.2635962763351296+2.289855072463768+2.3309352517985613+2.3216783216783217+2.360018509949098+null+2.042235790730032+0.000006222369997702123+0
```